# Draw star polymer in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I want to draw a structure similar to the below picture in tikz. The draw have to be in 2 dimensions and have 4 arms with each 6 monomers in each arm. Preferable each arm twist, like in the below structure, but the monomers are not allowed to overlap (this is the most important thing).

Are there any packages that can do this for me? I do have pythontex, so any python code, able to do it, is also a perfect solution. Or do I have to define all balls manually?

As noted in the comment. My intentions is not that you draw the picture for me, but more if there are any packages, that I can utilize to make it easier - such that I do not have to draw all circles manually.

[image: Star polymer]

I have drawn the initial structure with the center bead and the 4 starts of arms using the following piece of code:

First of course using tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
```

And then the 5 beads can be drawn as:

```
%Center ball
\shade[ball color=red!60] (0,0,0) circle (1cm);

%The 4 directions
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (2,0,0) circle (1cm);
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (-2,0,0) circle (1cm);
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,2,0) circle (1cm);
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,-2,0) circle (1cm);
```

Comment: The draw-this-picture-for-me type questions are generally not well received on this site, since it shows little effort at learning, on your part.

Comment: I did not mean this as a "draw this for me", more like, are there anything I can do to not having to draw everything manually, hence the tag. I will edit the question to emphasize this.

Comment: Well then, one way to improve your question would be to show the code you use to draw a single ball, and make the question about how to automate that for a string of balls.

Comment: use `markings` with the shaded ball mark to decorate your path

Comment: @percusse, I do not understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any package for your purpose. But you could start from examples such as this one: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/membrane-surface/ . But I don't know wether this picture could help or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a starting point for you, using the `decorations.markings` library of tikz as suggested by percusse. You just need to adjust the path in the way you want, to draw the 'star' correctly and the decoration of the path is done by tikz. By the way, is there any good reason, why you've started to define your coordinates in 3 dimensions? At least for getting the picture as shown in your question, this is not necessary.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
        markings,% switch on markings
        mark=% actually add a mark
        between positions 0 and 1 step 4mm % tells tikz to decorate path from beginning to end (0,1) and every 4 mm (diameter of the balls) defined two lines later
        with
            {\shade[ball color=red!80] (0,0) circle (.2cm);}% this is the definition of the actual marking.
        }
    ]
%
\path[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) .. controls (.5,1) and (1,1) .. (1.5,2);% postaction={decorate} tells tikz to decorate the path after it has been created. Note that \path itself doesn't draw anything but just creates the path to decorate.
\path[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) .. controls (-2,-1) and (-1,-2) .. (-1.5,-2);
\path[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1) and (-1,-2) .. (1.5,-2);
\path[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) .. controls (-1,1) and (0,1.5) .. (-1.5,2);
\shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,0) circle (.2cm);% draw a blue ball over the red one in the center
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I started off with wanted to have it in 3 dimensions, but reduced it to 2 dimensions - but I guess with this solution it is possible to extend.

Comment: Well actually I don't think this is going to work in 3d, since then you would have to create a curved path in 3d and create real balls (these are just circles filled with a shade) decorating your path. Tikz would not be the right tool for this. Anyway, I guess you're going to use this graphic in a 2d representation (on a sheet of paper, for a presentation, on a poster...) so making this in 3d would not have any benefit. Its just more complicated to do.

Answer (score 0):

For future references I also ended out with a solution building on the for loop defined in the link @DRi gave in the comments. The solution by @JMP is faster and is more elegant - however using for loops let me better control the number of beads and it is easier to make the path of the strings/arms random.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xvala}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yvala}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalb}{\xvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalb}{\yvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalc}{\xvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalc}{\yvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xvald}{\xvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yvald}{\yvala}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\size}{0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{\size/2}
\shade[ball color=red!60] (\xvala,\yvala) circle (\radius);
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,6}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\noisea}{(rnd-.5)*\size*\i/6*2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\noiseb}{(rnd-.5)*\size*\i/6*2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\noisec}{(rnd-.5)*\size*\i/6*2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\noised}{(rnd-.5)*\size*\i/6*2}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvala}{\xvala + sqrt((\size)^2-(\noisea)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yvala}{\yvala+\noisea}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalb}{\xvalb - sqrt((\size)^2-(\noiseb)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalb}{\yvalb+\noiseb}    

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yvalc}{\yvalc - sqrt((\size)^2-(\noisec)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvalc}{\xvalc+\noisec}    

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yvald}{\yvald + sqrt((\size)^2-(\noised)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xvald}{\xvald+\noised}        

    \shade[ball color=blue!60] (\xvala,\yvala) circle (\radius);
    \shade[ball color=blue!60] (\xvalb,\yvalb) circle (\radius);
    \shade[ball color=blue!60] (\xvalc,\yvalc) circle (\radius);
    \shade[ball color=blue!60] (\xvald,\yvald) circle (\radius);
}
```